# How to connect to Neptune using Version 4 Signing dependency

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have an EC2 instance that can connect to gremlin using the Gremlin Console, or by pulling in [this repository](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-java.html) and running the maven command.

However, when I use the recommended Version 4 signing dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile(
            ...
            // neptune sigv4
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"aws-java-sdk-core", version: "1.11.307"],
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer", version: "1.0"],
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4", version: "1.0"],
            ...
    )
}
```

On a very similar hello world program:

```
package com.test.neptune;

import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Cluster;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Result;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer;
import org.neo4j.cypher.internal.frontend.v2_3.repeat;

public class NeptuneExampleCopy {

    private static final String NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT = "my.endpoint.url";
    private static final int NEPTUNE_PORT = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // connect to the neptune cluster
            final Cluster cluster = Cluster.build()
                    .addContactPoint(NEPTUNE_ENDPOINT)
                    .port(NEPTUNE_PORT)
                    .channelizer(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.class)
                    .create();

            // run a traversal, print the results
            final Client client = cluster.connect();
            final ResultSet rs = client.submit("g.V().count()");
            for (Result r : rs) {
                    System.out.println(r);
            }

            // close the cluster
            cluster.close();
    }
}
```

Gradle throws the following exception:

```
Apr 25, 2019 5:24:21 PM io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer exceptionCaught
WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xd894eb28]
com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.exception.SigV4PropertiesNotFoundException: Unable to load SigV4 properties from any of the providers
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.ChainedSigV4PropertiesProvider.getSigV4Properties(ChainedSigV4PropertiesProvider.java:74)
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.loadProperties(AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.java:102)
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.<init>(AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.java:64)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.createHandler(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:210)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.configure(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:176)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:140)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:113)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:617)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$000(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1467)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAddedForAllHandlers(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1141)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.invokeHandlerAddedIfNeeded(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:666)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:510)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:214)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:198)
        at com.test.neptune.NeptuneExampleCopy.main(NeptuneExampleCopy.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submitAsync(Client.java:310)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submitAsync(Client.java:242)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:212)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client$ClusteredClient.chooseConnection(Client.java:499)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submitAsync(Client.java:305)
        ... 4 more
Apr 25, 2019 5:24:22 PM io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer exceptionCaught
WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xc3ff34e0]
com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.exception.SigV4PropertiesNotFoundException: Unable to load SigV4 properties from any of the providers
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.ChainedSigV4PropertiesProvider.getSigV4Properties(ChainedSigV4PropertiesProvider.java:74)
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.loadProperties(AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.java:102)
        at com.amazon.neptune.gremlin.driver.sigv4.AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.<init>(AwsSigV4ClientHandshaker.java:64)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.createHandler(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:210)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.configure(SigV4WebSocketChannelizer.java:176)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:140)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Channelizer$AbstractChannelizer.initChannel(Channelizer.java:92)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:113)
```

How could this code be fixed? Is there a better Version 4 signing dependency?

Answer (score 0):

SigV4 handler tries to fetch your AWS Credentials through multiple credential providers. If no credential provider was initialized, then you are bound to see this exception. How have you initialized your AWS Credentials? You could use any of the standard sources, like environment variables, or JVM system properties or the like. See the documentation below for more details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/iam-auth-connecting-gremlin-java.html

Update: Do make sure you are using the latest versions of all the packages and dependencies.

For example:

```
// neptune sigv4 [group: "com.amazonaws", 
name:"aws-java-sdk-core", version: "1.11.542"], 

[group: "com.amazonaws", 
name:"amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer", version: "1.0.4"], 

[group: "com.amazonaws", 
name:"amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4", version: "1.0.5"], 

// for neptune [group: "org.apache.tinkerpop", 
name: "gremlin-driver", version: "3.4.1"]
```

Comment: Hi, I've set environment variables as specified in the link in my initial post (which is the one you just resent me). Also, these credentials work for the gremlin console and when running the NeptuneGremlinSigV4Example provided in the link we both mentioned. I really think it's something else.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. How did you confirm that the gremlin console worked? Did you issue queries after the connection was established? Gremlin console has a weird output where it shows that you have connected to the server, but in reality it will connect only when you send your first query. Can you confirm that your query also worked ? After that, we can start digging deeper into what's going on in your example.

Comment: Yes, I was able to run a query that added a node in gremlin console `g.addV("Hello World")`, I closed gremlin console, and when I logged back in, `g.V().label()` spit out `Hello World`. I was able to do similar things in java by modifying the query in  https://github.com/aws/amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4.git I cannot connect when using the sigV4 library as a dependency.

Comment: How are you offering credentials to the client application?

Comment: Environment variables: `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key_id`
`export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret_access_key`
`export SERVICE_REGION=us-east-1|us-east-2|us-west-2|eu-west-1|eu-west-2|eu-central-1|ap-southeast-1|ap-southeast-2|ap-northeast-1|ap-south-1` as specified in step 3 of the neptune sigV4 guide

Comment: That's weird. I don't see any reason why Gremlin console worked and not your client application. Is it possible that your client application was started in a weird way that did not make the environment variables accessible to application? A simple way to test that would be to create a standard credential provider from your application, and make some AWS call (like ListInstances API of EC2). Or, a simpler way would be to explicitly read the environment variables that you set and print it out in the application. Can you try that and report what you get?

Comment: Using `System.getenv`, I confirmed that my app can read the variables, I also tried providing credentials with `System.setProperty`, which gave me a slightly different error: `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for an available host - check the client configuration and connectivity to the server if this message persists
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:214)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.submit(Client.java:198)
        at com.test.neptune.NeptuneExampleCopy.main(NeptuneExampleCopy.java:50)`

Comment: Just fixed this by updating dependency versions: `// neptune sigv4
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"aws-java-sdk-core", version: "1.11.542"],
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"amazon-neptune-sigv4-signer", version: "1.0.4"],
            [group: "com.amazonaws", name:"amazon-neptune-gremlin-java-sigv4", version: "1.0.5"], // for neptune
            [group: "org.apache.tinkerpop", name: "gremlin-driver", version: "3.4.1"],`